# Set wallpaper from ViewPager

Tags: android, eclipse, gallery, android-viewpager, wallpaper

I have a ViewPager in which I change images with swype. Now I want to make button which will set current image that user is seeing as wallpaper. How to implement onPageSelected or something similar that will do the job?

Code:

```
package com.example.app;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

      }

          private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
            private int[] mImages = new int[] {
                R.drawable.image1,
                R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3,
                R.drawable.image4

            };


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
              return mImages.length;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
              return view == ((ImageView) object);
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
              Context context = MainActivity.this;
              ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
              int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                  R.dimen.padding_medium);
              imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
              imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
              imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
              ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
              return imageView;
            } 


            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, final int position, Object object) {
              ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
            }
          }
    }
}
```

Button code i used before, but don't know how to implement it now in ViewPager:

```
Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1); 
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());            
                                try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(mImages[position]);
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper ok!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
          }
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Here you can set the wallpaper
                    curruntPosition=arg0;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

and then

```
    Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1); 
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());            
                                try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(mImages[curruntPosition]);
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper ok!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
          }
       });
```

and do not forget the declare a global variable

```
int curruntPosition=0;
```

Comment: I'm not quire sure how to implement this what you wrote in code I posted. I would appreciate if you paste your code in original code on proper location. Thanks in advance!

Comment: add above code under this line `viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);` you really a programmer? It is as simple as your name :)

Comment: Thank you sir. The only problem is that onClick method is not working as it should inside of onPageSelected.

Comment: why you want `onClick` in `onPageSelected` ??

Comment: Because I have button which sets image as wallpaper. I don't want it to be set as wallpaper every time when I swype to next image. I want to make that user click on button and set image he wants as wallpaper.

Comment: ~ah then you only need the position of current image?

Comment: Yes, so i can call it from myWallpaperManager.setResource(mImages[arg0]);

Comment: then you need to daclare a global variable and update it in `onPageSelected`. see my edit. hope it will solve your problem!

Comment: Great. Thank you very much for your time and help. I managed to do it, had to declare more global variables, but it's ok now. Thanks one more time! :)