# How to display popup option of "set as wallpaper" when user press on image for 3-5 sec in inageviewer app?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Following... this link ..[How to set image as wall paper in viewpager app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476178/how-to-set-image-as-wall-paper-in-viewpager-app). I am able to set wallpaper directly located in my drawable folder. However, i want to give user a chance to set wallpaper by displaying pop up dialogue box which should be displayed. When user clicks on images for 3-5 sec.

I am kind of new to android programming.. So, please help..

Answer (score 0):

1. android framework already supporting class "alertDialogue.builder". you can set message whatever you wanna show in addition to dialogue buttons, title etc.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

1. 5sec is too long to stay in one fingerpoint. in onsimplegesturedetector class, there is already "long press" detector

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html

Comment: could you please provide the code and let me know where to use it ? it would be very helpful ...

Comment: i added other answer !

Comment: @ ejin .. could you please tell where can I get wallpaper image id ?

Answer (score 0):

you can set your own ontouchListener that implements onTouchListener that has gesture detector, detects long press and can show dialogue .

there can be better way but I'm using this logic in my project so you can reference and fix it if you find better way

```
findViewById("your wall paper image id").onTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());



class MyOnTouchListener implements onTouchListener{
    GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(new SimpleOnGestureListener(){
        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

            alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("click yes to set wallpaper!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    //setting wallpaper
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me where should I paste the code ... to be specific in mainactivity.java or imageadapter.java